# Bad performance when filtering Azure logs - WCF Data Services filters

Tags: wcf, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-table-storage

Azure Diagnostics is pushing Windows Events into a storage table "WADWindowsEventLogsTable".

I would like to query this storage Table using VisualStudio(2015) and [CloudExplorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/84e83a7c-9606-4f9f-83dd-0f6182f13add).

As this table has an huge content, I'm indefinitely waiting for the results..

Here is a query sample:

```
EventId eq 4096 and Timestamp gt datetime'2016-06-24T08:20:00' and Timestamp lt datetime'2016-06-24T10:00:00'
```

I suppose that this query is correct ?

Does exist a way to improve performance ?

- filter result columns ?
- return only TOP X results ?
- another usefull tips ?

I know that a better way would be to script that; for example using Python, but I would like to use the UI as much as possible..

---

(Edit) following **Gaurav Mantri** answer I used this little C# program to build my query. The answer is so quick and that solve my initial performance issue:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string startDate = "24 June 2016 8:20:00 AM";
        string endDate   = "24 June 2016 10:00:00 AM";

        string startPKey = convertDateToPKey(startDate);
        string endPKey   = convertDateToPKey(endDate);
        Debug.WriteLine("(PartitionKey gt '" + startPKey + "'"
            + " and PartitionKey le '" + endPKey +"')"
            + " and (EventId eq 4096)"
            );
    }

    private static string convertDateToPKey(string myDate)
    {
        System.DateTime dt = System.Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);
        long dt2ticks = dt.Ticks;
        string ticks = System.Convert.ToString(dt2ticks);
        return "0" + ticks;
    }
```

NB: for those, like me, who are searching so far away how to export results to a CSV file, you should know that this icon is your answer (and it's not a 'undo' ;) ): [image: CloudExplorer-Table-Export action button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, you're filtering on `Timestamp` attribute which is not indexed (Only `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` attributes are indexed). Thus your query is making a full table scan (i.e. going from the 1st record till the time it finds a matching record) and hence not optimized.

In order to avoid full table scan, please use `PartitionKey` in your query. In case of `WADWindowsEventLogsTable`, the `PartitionKey` essentially represents the date/time value in ticks. What you would need to do is convert the date/time range for which you want to get the data into ticks, prepend a `0` in front of it and then use it in the query.

So your query would be something like:

```
(PartitionKey gt 'from date/time value in ticks prepended with 0' and PartitionKey le 'to date/time value in ticks prepended with 0') and (EventId eq 4096)
```

I wrote a blog post about it some time ago that you may find useful: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/